# Cannot easy_install IMDbPY

Tags: python, windows-7, easy-install, imdbpy

I'm trying to install the IMDbPY module to Python using easy_install. However, I've never used Python before and kept getting stuck on using easy_install or pip install. Since I'm using Windows 7, I tried running the following code in command prompt:

easy_install IMDbPY

A flashing cursor then appears on the next line, but nothing happens after a long wait. I tried installing other packages such as SQLObject using easy install and pip install as well, but the same result occurs. It seems that whenever I try to use easy_install, cmd just freezes and never actually finishes the installation.

Am I using easy_install incorrectly? If so, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to bypass using easy_install by changing the directory to each package's installation folder and running "python setup.py install" in command prompt.